# What's the proper hash syntax in Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby

Should I use ?

```
{ :first_name => "Mathieu", :last_name => "Jackson" }
```

or

```
{ first_name: "Mathieu", last_name: "Jackson" }
```

Comment: the original can be replaced by latter. If its not, that will show syntax error.

Comment: @sawa OP isn't asking what works, rather what "should" be used. It's likely off-topic, but that's all.

Comment: @DaveNewton You are right regarding the text, but if you look at the title, it is asking what works.

Comment: @sawa Don't even need the docs to find out what works, though, so I think it's clear what the question is. OP seems to know what's legal and is instead asking about pegged syntax. Just my interpretation.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed.  It just solved a problem for me.

Comment: no idea why this is closed, just helped me find what the Ruby 2.0 hash syntax is after a google search, a poor close decision indeed

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference between the two, so it is personal preference. Though I would expect most people writing new code for 2.0 will use the second format.

It's important to note that if you are developing for open-source / public consumption and want a wide user base you should use the "old" style of hashes. Ruby 1.8.x, as well as JRuby and other ruby implementations apart from RMI, does not support the terse syntax.

Comment: also JRuby supports the :a => 1 syntax, iirc

Comment: Correct, as of JRuby 1.7.0 the terse syntax was made default (1.9 mode), but earlier versions expected/used the older style of hashes.

Comment: There is a very important difference between the two. If you want to use a variable as a key you will need to use the hash rocket.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "should".

I prefer the 1.9 syntax unless there are symbols-as-values, then I think it looks silly.

This means I don't use them uniformly, it depends on what the hash values are–but I always use the same style in a single immediate hash.

Answer (score 2):

The first one should be using if you are looking for backwards compatibility. But the second one is neater.

Answer (score 1):

Use what you want. There is no sacred meaning in that. But it is highly recommended to use it uniformly.